# Forking a process in Java redirecting input/output/error stream efficiently

Tags: java, process, io, fork, nio

in a bash script, if I execute an external program (i.e. 'bash') that is executed "inline". I mean that the process is not spanned in background and the stdin/stdout/stderr of the child process coincide with the one of the bash script itself.

So if my bash script contains

```
#!/bin/sh
bash
```

what happens is that the user can run my script and when bash is executed he will be able to type commands in the standard input of bash and see the results of the command on stdout/stderr.

This is what I mean that the child process is run "inline".

In java the process is spanned in background, so the Process.getOutputStream()/Process.getInputStream()/Process.getErrorStream are not "inline" with System.in/System.out/System.err.

What I want to do in my java program is to reproduce the behavior of what happens when I execute a process as in the above example of the bash script.

After some google searches I come out with this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    String[] cmdarray = {"bash"};
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);

    StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(),
            System.err);

    StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(),
            System.out);

    StreamGobbler inputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(System.in,
            proc.getOutputStream());

    errorGobbler.start();
    outputGobbler.start();
    inputGobbler.start();

    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    errorGobbler.join(); // Handle condition where the
    outputGobbler.join(); // process ends before the threads finish
    System.exit(exitVal);
}

class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        this.is = is;
        this.os = os;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int c;
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                os.write(c);
                os.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }
    }
}
```

But hey, there are 3 threads! plus the thread spanned by executing the process!

There must be a better way. Something like:

```
Runtime.execForeground("bash", System.in, System.out, System.err);
```

or just:

```
Runtime.execForeground("bash");
```

which executes the process "inline" as it works with many script languages.

Maybe another possibility is to use nonblocking I/O to have the stdin/stdout/stderr copied to System.in/out/err in a single thread? Any example?

Comment: Don't worry about the threads. Your only alternative is to find something based on Java NIO, but the offering there is scant, very much due to the fact that the world doesn't worry about the extra treads -- it's the Java way for handling this. NIO is an order of magnitude more cumbersome to code against, and the benefits are negligible.

Comment: I think that java API for process execution is wrong.
I would expect to be able to do something like:
    ProcessFork pf = new Process(...)
    pf.setStandardInput(System.in);
    pf.setStandardOutput(System.out);
    pf.setStandardError(System.err);
    pf.setForeground();
    Process p = pf.execute();

or something like that

Comment: True, this is obviously not a feature that JDK supports out of the box. There's a solid chance for a library out there doing pretty much the same thing that you outlined here, though.

Comment: There is this library http://commons.apache.org/exec/; don't know if it solves my problem, but I'm having a look right now.

Comment: Update: commons-exec is the same stuff which is included in ant for the exec task, and it does the same thread stuff as I explained above, in a much more complicated way. Not for me.

Comment: Looks like you're gonna have to implement their `LogOutputStream` and just use the `InputStreamPumper`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant -- that you would find a lib that has the same basic code that you have. I see it was a quite ambiguous statement.

Comment: Still this is horrible and very limited. In a bash script (and possibly in C), I could even run an editor and this will work fine. With the code I posted I can't run, for example 'vim'; it works, but it works really bad. It's not the first time I have those kind of issues with Java, I wonder why it has to be so hard to put the jvm in pause and execute an external process as all the scripting languages do.

Comment: Java was never positioned as a good choice for scripting, due to high memory demands, slow startup, etc., so the features didn't evolve in that direction, especially features that you mention that are not easy to achieve in a platform-independent manner.

Comment: load startup is improved a lot since years, and memory is not an issue on today's computing. Still, the interoperability with other system processes is important also in enterprise applications, as well as desktop applications. In my case, I am not needing this for a script, but for a web application which administers some unix resources, so I am implementing some utilities to interact with command line tools. Those limitations are quite an hassle.